# ActiveRecord update model while rollback another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, transactions

Lets put a bit of context on this question. Given an Ecommerce application in Ruby on Rails. Let's deal with 2 models for example. User and CreditCard.

My User is in the system after a registration no issue there. 
CreditCard is a model with the credit card information (yes I know about PCI compliance but that's not the point here)

In the Credit Card model, I include a callback after_validation that will do a validation of the credit card against your bank.

Let me put some simple code here.

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum :status, [:active, :banned]
  has_one :credit_card
end
```

**models/credit_card.rb**

```
class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  after_validation :validate_at_bank

  def validate_at_bank
    result = Bank.validate(info) #using active_merchant by exemple
    unless result.success
      errors.add {credit_card: "Bank doesn't validate"}
      user.banned!
    end
  end
end
```

**controllers/credit_cards_controller.rb**

```
class CreditCardsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @credit_card = CreditCard.new(credit_card_params) # from Strong Parameters
    if @credit_card.save
      render #success
    else
      render #failure
    end
  end
end
```

**What causing me issue**
It look like Rails opens a transaction in ActiveRecord when I'm doing a new. At this point nothing is send to the database.

When the bank reject the credit card, I want to ban the user. I do this by calling banned! Now I realised this update is going to the same transaction. I can see the update, but once the save doesn't go though, everything is rollback from both models. The credit card is not saved (that is good), the user is not saved (this is not good since I want to ban him)

I try to add a Transaction wrapper, but this only add a database checkpoint. I could create a delayed job for the ban, but this seems to me to be overkill. I could use a after_rollback callback, but I'm not sure this is the right way. I'm a bit surprise, I never caught this scenario before, leading me to believe that my patern is not correct or the point where I make this call is incorrect.

Comment: Ok I must have screw up badly somewhere, because I can't replicate this on a side projet. I'll investigate anyway and at least post the solution to this problem.

Comment: Ok The @credit_card.save in the controller start the transaction. This is fine and this make sense. Now if I would like to call user.update_column(info: "Not well") from with the start of the transaction how will I do that ?

Comment: Found some information on the parallel processing. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20743433/552443 You do this by starting a thread and reconnecting the database from a connection pool. I'm sure this is working but I kind of finding this overkill for a simple update of a table. Hopefully somebody will bring some idea to the table.

Answer (score 0):

After much review and more digging I came up with 3 ways to handle this situation. Depending on the needs you have, one of them should be good for you.

1. Separate thread and new database connection
2. Calling the validate function before the save explictly
3. Send the task to be perform to a Delayed Job

   - **Separate thread**

   The following answer shows how to do this operation.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20743433/552443

This will work, but again not that nice and simple.

- **Call valid? before the save**

This is a very quick solution. The issue is that a new developer could erase the valid? line thinking that the .save will do the job properly.

- **Calling Delayed Job**

This could be any ActionJob provider. You can send the task to banned the user in a separate thread. Depending on your setup this is quite clean but not everybody needs DelayedJob.

If you see anything please add it to a new solution of the comments.